# Wormhole Based Warfare

Tags: science-based, warfare, space-warfare

Let's say that, theoretically, a civilization is capable of utilizing wormholes for travelling to the stars, this wormholes, eventually get turned into a device that can be used as for travel, as a war machine.

I don't know the limitations of wormholes, if they have mass, spin or other properties, but let's assume a relatively realistic wormhole.

This wormhole can be opened anywhere, space and even in atmosphere. What would be the implications and changes in warfare this device will induce?

Would it make space warfare irrelevant thanks to being able to destroy anything with the gravitational pull of the Wormhole? Would wormholes be used on atmosphere and change ground warfare? Would be ever a counter for them?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, one I'd like to approach, but you should really hammer out the specifics more. Depending on the theory, their properties vary a lot. You mention gravitational pull. Wormhole mass ranges from "mass of the universe" to "massless". Also, a "relatively realistic" wormhole isn't one that can be opened anywhere. They're usually imagined as being created in microscopic pairs and pried apart & enlarged. A delicate process requiring a mountain of machinery.

Comment: Hi Dakka. I closed your question, not to get rid of it, but to give you a chance to redirect it. You have some interesting questions, but asking more than one question is *literally* a reason to close questions (VTC:Needs More Focus). Worse, you really haven't worked out how to use wormholes (c.f. the duplicate question). A [number of questions about using wormholes as weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+wormhole+weapon) have been asked. I'd like you to review them and think about what one question you still want to ask. Like I said, I think there's a good Q here.

Comment: One very important element that also isn't considered; what is the *size* of the wormhole? Does an object get immediately to the other side like a doorway or go through a tunneling process? And what does the tunnel look like? is it straight, bend, perhaps twisting endlessly like a tornado you have to navigate through? These all impact your answer.